# how to compare array of check-boxes and with the string and to check only that boxes

Tags: php, codeigniter

I an in edit mode of a file with multiple check boxes now the problem is i have data in string form and getting value after for-each is 1 single number or object how can i compare then check only checked boxes which values exist in the string

```
<div class="form-group">
    <ul id="id_extras">
    <?php
    $category = array(
        1 => 'Air Conditioning',
        2 => 'Alarm/Anti-Theft System',
        3 => 'AM/FM Radio',
        4 => 'Aux Audio In',
        5 => 'Bluetooth System',
        6 => 'Body Kit',
        7 => 'Brush Guard',
        8 => 'Cassette Player',
        9 => 'CD Player',
       10 => 'Climate Control',              
    );


    var_dump($values['extras']);
    //results are string "1,2,3,4,5,7,8"

    foreach ($category as $k => $v) {
    ?>
        <li>
            <label for="id_extras_<?= $k; ?>">
                <input class="multiple-select" id="id_extras_<?= $k; ?>" name="extras[]"
                       type="checkbox"
                       value="<?= $k; ?>" 
                       <?php in_array($values['extras'], $k) ? 'checked' : '' ?>> <?= $v; ?>
            </label>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you are attempting to check the boxes that match, you have it mostly right:

```
<?php in_array($values['extras'], $k) ? 'checked' : '' ?>
```

This makes the determination, and returns a string, but doesn't print it. The code you want would be this:

```
<?= in_array($k, explode(',', $values['extras'])) ? 'checked' : '' ?>
```

- `<?=` is a shorthand operator for `print`.
- We explode `extras` as it is a comma separated string, but we want to search it as an array.
- `in_array()` arguments are: needle, haystack

The only other modification here is that it may be wise to render the attribute as `checked="checked"` for XHTML compliance.